# ngOptions non-strict comparison with ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-select

Is there any way to perform a non-strict comparison in the `<select>` `ngOptions` in order to set the initial value from a model? For example, if the model is an integer and the options key property is a string value, the `<select>` initial value unfortunately is not set.

#### HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <select data-ng-model="model" data-ng-options="option.id as option.text for option in options"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = '2'; // This works as an integer (2) but not as a string ('2')
    $scope.options = [
      {id: 1, text: '11111'},
      {id: 2, text: '22222'}, // I want this option to be selected
      {id: 3, text: '33333'}
    ];
});
```

Comment: What is purpose of using model as  string  ?

Comment: @AnilKumarArya I hardcoded the model value just for an example. In my real app, the model value is loaded from the remote servers. Some servers provide strings, some provide integers.

Comment: Then parse it to convert to one common type -- using parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you need to add the "track by" keywords in your ng-options, such as :

```
    <select data-ng-model="model" data-ng-options="option.id as option.text for option in options track by option.id"></select>
```